# Как получить переменную в функцию, а затем вывести её на страницу в php

Tags: php

У меня есть функция в config.php с нужным мне текстом

```
файл config.php
    $titles = "Текст";
```

Я подключаю этот файл в файл functions.php и хочу получить перемменую из первого файла, а затем вывести её на страницу index.php через foreach такой переменной

```
файл functions.php


    <?php
    include "admin/data.php"; 
        function getServices(){
            return [
                '1' => [
                    'id' => 1, 
                    'description' => '<?=$titles["description"]?>', <-- тут должна быть переменная из файла config.php
               ]
            ];
        }
```

Comment: *Я подключаю этот файл* - где вы подключаете config, почему вы хотите к переменной title обращаться как $titles["description"] ?

Comment: ну если нельзя менять getServices (например превратив её в анонимную функцию) или подключить конфиг внутри функции, то способов не особо много.... **в самом плохом варианте** использовать внутри функции `global $titles;`